# Couldn't connect to https port because of misssing SSL certificates

Tags: c#, https, ssl-certificate, windows-7-x64, iis-express

On Windows 7, for ASP Web API solution, not able to connect to https port (other than 443) because of missing SSL port certificates(44300 +) which I checked it using "netsh http show sslcert". I tried adding certificate manually but it didn't work with my solution.
The binding statements for those ports are correct in "applicationhost.config" of IIS express. 
"".These certificates are automatically generated on windows server 2008.
In the browser it shows is "This webpage is not available".

Can Somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS you will need to add a binding to that site for the port you want to use.

See this for additional help

http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm

or

IIS Express
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx